# How do I pass a class to a method in Nashorn?

Tags: java-8, nashorn

One of our scripts has the following line, calling a method in Ant to get a provider:

```
var provider = resource.as(org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileProvider);
```

Since updating to Java 8, this now fails with an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.StaticClass to java.lang.Class
        at sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.newClassCastException(ValueConversions.java:461)
        at sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.castReference(ValueConversions.java:456)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.getFileHack(<eval>:131)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.runScript(<eval>:207)
```

I'm trying to figure out what has changed from the Nashorn docs, but it isn't particularly clear. The following change to use what I see in the documented examples gives the same error:

```
var provider = resource.as(Java.type("org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileProvider"));
```

How do I convert a StaticClass to a Java Class to pass it in here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.class`:

```
var provider = resource.as(org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileProvider.class);
```

or

```
var provider = resource.as(Java.type("org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileProvider").class);
```

Just like in Java :-)

Comment: Rats. I knew it would be something simple. I even found some method like getRepresentedClass() and discovered that calling that didn't help. :D

Comment: For some reason, the examples Oracle and Mozilla Rhino give do *not* have the .class. Misleading... good this has been answered here. (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/FAQ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsarrays )